Are there any good python libraries for modulation/demodulation? for ex BPSK,QPSK,16PSK,QAM,16QAM, ect
Question in the title.
Are there any good python libraries for modulation/demodulation? for ex BPSK,QPSK,16PSK,QAM,16QAM, etc...

Another library to mention is the komm library.
https://pypi.org/project/komm/
It's documentation lists as influences the scikit-compy library @AHT mentions, as well as the MATLAB communications toolbox as well as GNU Radio and SageMath. It may or may not have more features than compy (I am less familiar with compy) but may be worth comparing the two.
The code implementation AHT provided is nearly identical with komm with some minor changes, basically all that AHT wrote with the following:
import komm
M=16
qam = komm.QAModulation(M)
# 16QAM Modulation
modulated_signal = qam.modulate(bits)
# 16QAM Demodulation
demodulated_bits = qam.demodulate(received_signal, 'hard')

scikit-commpy appears to have more direct support for MIMO and OFDM modulations. Unfortunately scikit-commpy isn't actively supported based on my rudimentary metrics: it hasn't been updated since Oct 10, 2022, with 18 open issues many without responses. In comparison the last release of komm was Feb 27, 2024 with one open issue.

Yes, there is. Check out scikit-commpy.
Here is an example of QAM modulation and demodulation.
import numpy as np
import commpy.modulation as mod
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define parameters
M = 16  # Modulation order (e.g., 16 for 16QAM)
SNR_dB = 20  # Signal-to-noise ratio in dB

# Generate random bit stream
bits = np.random.randint(0, 2, int(1e4))

# 16QAM Modulation
qam = mod.QAMModem(M)
modulated_signal = qam.modulate(bits)

# Add AWGN noise
noise_std = np.sqrt(0.5 * 10**(-SNR_dB / 10))
noise = noise_std * (np.random.randn(len(modulated_signal)) + 1j * np.random.randn(len(modulated_signal)))
received_signal = modulated_signal + noise

# 16QAM Demodulation
demodulated_bits = qam.demodulate(received_signal, 'hard')

# Calculate Bit Error Rate (BER)
ber = np.sum(bits != demodulated_bits) / len(bits)
print(f'Bit Error Rate (BER): {ber}')

# Plotting the constellation diagram
plt.scatter(received_signal.real, received_signal.imag, color='red', s=1)
plt.title('16QAM Constellation Diagram')
plt.xlabel('In-phase')
plt.ylabel('Quadrature')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

```

